# Why does time for initialize array different

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Why

```
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int size = 3333333;
        int[][][] arr = new int[size][6][2];
//        int[][][] arr= new int[2][6][size];
        pr(System.currentTimeMillis() - t );
```

prints `5000 ms`
but

```
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int size = 3333333;
//        int[][][] arr = new int[size][6][2];
        int[][][] arr= new int[2][6][size];
        pr(System.currentTimeMillis() - t );
```

prints `44 ms`

Second solution 115 time faster

Comment: How do you run this snippet? could you post the whole method? How many times have you run them? How many initial cycles did you run? Benchmarking Java operations is not a trivial thing...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java - The way you are doing this is unlikely to produce any meaningful results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simplier to test `int[][]`

```
int[][] arr = new int[size][2];
```

In this case you have to allocate `size` pieces of memory with size of 16 bytes.

And in this case

```
int[][] arr = new int[2][size];
```

you have only to allocate 2 pieces of memory of size*8 bytes.

And allocating is expensive operation.

Comment: 115 times faster? I think this is an issue related to JVM initialization, and initial optimization process...

Comment: With or without optimization in 1st sample you have to store many object (array) and allocate them all in heap and in second sample there is only 2 objects

Comment: I must admit it, you're right. I created a small, proper-ish benchmark around it, and the result is (roughly) the same. I think it's time for me to do some research around it...